# Animation help!

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I just have a quick question. I am running through an array of images using CCAnimation to make a football spiral. Like so:

```
// load the football's animation frames as textures and create a sprite frame
frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
NSString* file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Football%i.png", i];
CCTexture2D* texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:file];
CGSize texSize = texture.contentSize;
CGRect texRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, texSize.width, texSize.height);
CCSpriteFrame* frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:texture rect:texRect];
[frames addObject:frame];
}

// create an animation object from all the sprite animation frames
CCAnimation* anim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:frames delay:0.03f];

// run the animation by using the CCAnimate action
CCAnimate* animate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim];
CCRepeatForever* repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animate];
[self runAction:repeat];
```

This works really well, but I am wondering how I would create another animation with this same array that would make the football look like it slowly stops spinning? I know that delay:0.03f is controlling how fast the ball spirals, so is there a to some how make the delay slowly end up at 0.0f or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use `[animate setDuration:[animate getDuration] + 0.1]` to increase the delay time. and you have to increase th delay time to make football look like it's spinning slower. and after a while you just stop deactivate animate. if you want to create another animation using the anim frames you can call `[CCAnimation AnimationWithFrames:[anim getFrames]]`

Comment: I did what you said but it doesn't seem like it is accessing the animation. I created a method with this code in it [anim setDelay:[anim delay] + 0.1]; and another method with to schedule it, and it is all running, but the football is still spiraling at full speed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sorry i made mistake and corrected my answer you had to change the duration of your animate instance not the delay of animation, of couse if you want to create another animate from this you have to change the delay aswell but in your case it seems only changeing duration is enough(i tested it myself this time)